# Trouble working on wordpress development locally due to file permissions

Tags: 12.04, command-line, permissions, wordpress

I am a newbie Wordpress developer switched to Ubuntu 12.04 from win 7. I find these root file permissions really difficult to deal with. I installed "Geany" but can't open root files with it.

How do you work on lamp with such kind of permissions.
Please share few tips, it is very frustrating and time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

If those files are NOT in /var/www/ and are part of the system then yes you should use command line and something like `nano` or `vi` with sudo in front.

If part of the LAMP, for instance they are in /var/www/ I would advice changing those files to the default apache user (or www-data) and add yourself to the group this user is part of. There is no need to use user `root` for this.

And then the `group` permission is what you are looking for. If you add users to a group then they can edit files as if they where the user. We have a group "develope(r)" where "apache" and all users in our company are part of. We can edit from Windows over the network files that are on an Ubuntu server with no problems.

More info on groups:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116708/adding-apache-to-a-user-group-file-upload-permission
- https://serverfault.com/questions/6895/whats-the-best-way-of-handling-permissions-for-apache2s-user-www-data-in-var
- https://superuser.com/questions/355220/group-permissions-for-apache

Comment: I got it, i need to make a group and add myself to it with permisiions to openly access var/www directory. Please tell me how to make these groups and what permissions do i need to give to myself to edit var/www files.

Comment: Yes, that is the short version ;)